# Fixed Navigation On-Scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

Looking for the side navigation of this template to become fixed when a user scrolls past it for easier navigation. What I'm using doesn't seem to be working, need another set of eyes.

I cant figure it out for some reason, any help would be much appreciated P: I've barely got any bearings on javascript/jquery. Emphasis on barely ;)

---

Alternatively, how would I make the element stop once it reached a certain point on the page?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $(window).scroll(function () {
      console.log($(window).scrollTop())
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 280) {
      $('#fixed').addClass('stick');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 281) {
      $('#fixed').removeClass('stick');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Oswald);
body {
  background: url(http://orig02.deviantart.net/240a/f/2016/162/7/f/into_the_white__by_thehartless-da5x0or.png) center fixed no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position-y: 0%;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

a:link {
 color: #8ac3e4;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 1s;
}

a:visited {
 color: #8ac3e4;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
 color: #bde7ff;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 1s;
}

#logo {
  color: #fff;
  font: 65px Oswald;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-top: 8%;
}

#container {
  background: rgba(219, 227, 230, 0.80);
  color: #333;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-top: 10%;
  font: 15px Open Sans;
  min-width: 850px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

#content {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1% 22%;
}

.thead {
  padding: 3% 0;
  color: #fff;
  font: 25px Open Sans;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.trow1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgb(243, 243, 243);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.guide {
  display: table;
}

.guide .title {
  background: url('http://orig01.deviantart.net/57d2/f/2016/236/b/0/itw_map_sigless_by_marinatedmermaid_dabhbyl_by_thehartless-daf57xe.png') #ddd no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  font: 25px Oswald;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
}

.guide .overlay {
  background: rgba(250, 250, 250, .7);
  padding: 3%;
  
}

.guide_row {
  display: table-row;
}

.guide_nav {
  width: 25%;
  max-width: 225px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #c8cacc;
  padding: 3%;
  color: #fff;
}

#fixed {
  width: auto;
}

#fixed.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}

.guide_nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.guide_nav li {
  background: #9a9b9b;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.guide_nav a:link {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 1s;
}

.guide_nav a:visited {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.guide_nav a:hover,
a:active {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 1s;
}

.guide_content {
  display: table_cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 3%;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.guide_content:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}


.guide_sep {
  opacity: .2;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.guide_map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 662px;
  background: url('http://orig01.deviantart.net/57d2/f/2016/236/b/0/itw_map_sigless_by_marinatedmermaid_dabhbyl_by_thehartless-daf57xe.png') no-repeat bottom;
  background-size: cover;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">into the white</div>

<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="thead">guide</div>
    <div class="trow1">
      <div class="guide">
        <div class="guide_row">
          <div class="guide_nav">
            <div id="fixed">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#setting">Setting</a></li>
              <li><a href="#map">Map</a></li>
              <li><a href="#lore">Religion & Lore</a></li>
              <li><a href="#culture">Culture</a></li>
              <li><a href="#characters">Characters</a></li>
              <li><a href="#strains">Strains</a></li>
              <li><a href="#ethyr">Ethyr</a></li>
              <li><a href="#leveling">Leveling</a></li>             
              <li><a href="#beastiary">Beastiary</a></li>
              <li><a href="#fauna">Fauna</a></li>
              <li><a href="#rules">Rules</a></li>
              <li><a href="#mechanics">Game Mechanics</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div id="introduction" class="title"><div class="overlay">Introduction</div></div>
          <div class="guide_content">
<p>Phasellus sed metus rhoncus, suscipit odio eu, congue ex. Cras eget velit vitae metus placerat varius sed eget libero. In vestibulum lobortis risus, sed molestie dui commodo id. Vivamus nec placerat nisi, a sollicitudin risus. Vivamus non risus arcu. Morbi ex ante, tincidunt vel rutrum vel, dapibus nec felis. Pellentesque sed ipsum nisl. Fusce volutpat erat tristique dolor congue, ac porttitor mi venenatis. Phasellus tincidunt, nibh sed semper ornare, velit ligula vehicula tortor, et pulvinar urna nunc laoreet augue. Morbi ac justo eu lorem blandit suscipit sit amet in nisl. Suspendisse egestas ipsum sed elit commodo congue. Nullam ultricies egestas interdum. Proin dolor velit, pharetra in imperdiet placerat, malesuada vitae nisi. Phasellus vel rhoncus nunc.</p>
          </div>
          <div id="map" class="title"><div class="overlay">Map</div></div>
          <div class="guide_map">
            </div>
          <div id="setting" class="title"><div class="overlay">Setting</div></div>
          <div class="guide_content">
<p>Phasellus sed metus rhoncus, suscipit odio eu, congue ex. Cras eget velit vitae metus placerat varius sed eget libero. In vestibulum lobortis risus, sed molestie dui commodo id. Vivamus nec placerat nisi, a sollicitudin risus. Vivamus non risus arcu. Morbi ex ante, tincidunt vel rutrum vel, dapibus nec felis. Pellentesque sed ipsum nisl. Fusce volutpat erat tristique dolor congue, ac porttitor mi venenatis. Phasellus tincidunt, nibh sed semper ornare, velit ligula vehicula tortor, et pulvinar urna nunc laoreet augue. Morbi ac justo eu lorem blandit suscipit sit amet in nisl. Suspendisse egestas ipsum sed elit commodo congue. Nullam ultricies egestas interdum. Proin dolor velit, pharetra in imperdiet placerat, malesuada vitae nisi. Phasellus vel rhoncus nunc.</p>

<p>Vestibulum tincidunt sem arcu, sit amet mollis dolor volutpat at. Integer tincidunt vel augue at efficitur. Aenean semper mi urna, sit amet suscipit augue tristique nec. Fusce in metus venenatis, volutpat libero ut, porta sapien. Vestibulum auctor, purus id consequat condimentum, orci sem dignissim velit, vel fermentum libero diam venenatis lorem. Aliquam lacinia scelerisque accumsan. Proin sed euismod lacus. Fusce et leo auctor, efficitur odio et, pellentesque risus. Etiam ultrices arcu ac ipsum rhoncus ullamcorper. Phasellus vel condimentum orci. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam pulvinar euismod vestibulum. Nam nec lorem lobortis, lobortis dui luctus, ullamcorper tellus. Duis et erat pretium eros blandit aliquet id vel mi.</p>
          </div>
          <div id="lore" class="title"><div class="overlay">Religion & Lore</div></div>
          <div class="guide_content">
<p>Phasellus sed metus rhoncus, suscipit odio eu, congue ex. Cras eget velit vitae metus placerat varius sed eget libero. In vestibulum lobortis risus, sed molestie dui commodo id. Vivamus nec placerat nisi, a sollicitudin risus. Vivamus non risus arcu. Morbi ex ante, tincidunt vel rutrum vel, dapibus nec felis. Pellentesque sed ipsum nisl. Fusce volutpat erat tristique dolor congue, ac porttitor mi venenatis. Phasellus tincidunt, nibh sed semper ornare, velit ligula vehicula tortor, et pulvinar urna nunc laoreet augue. Morbi ac justo eu lorem blandit suscipit sit amet in nisl. Suspendisse egestas ipsum sed elit commodo congue. Nullam ultricies egestas interdum. Proin dolor velit, pharetra in imperdiet placerat, malesuada vitae nisi. Phasellus vel rhoncus nunc.</p>

<p>Vestibulum tincidunt sem arcu, sit amet mollis dolor volutpat at. Integer tincidunt vel augue at efficitur. Aenean semper mi urna, sit amet suscipit augue tristique nec. Fusce in metus venenatis, volutpat libero ut, porta sapien. Vestibulum auctor, purus id consequat condimentum, orci sem dignissim velit, vel fermentum libero diam venenatis lorem. Aliquam lacinia scelerisque accumsan. Proin sed euismod lacus. Fusce et leo auctor, efficitur odio et, pellentesque risus. Etiam ultrices arcu ac ipsum rhoncus ullamcorper. Phasellus vel condimentum orci. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam pulvinar euismod vestibulum. Nam nec lorem lobortis, lobortis dui luctus, ullamcorper tellus. Duis et erat pretium eros blandit aliquet id vel mi.</p>
          </div>
          <div id="culture" class="title"><div class="overlay">Culture</div></div>
          <div class="guide_content">
<p>Phasellus sed metus rhoncus, suscipit odio eu, congue ex. Cras eget velit vitae metus placerat varius sed eget libero. In vestibulum lobortis risus, sed molestie dui commodo id. Vivamus nec placerat nisi, a sollicitudin risus. Vivamus non risus arcu. Morbi ex ante, tincidunt vel rutrum vel, dapibus nec felis. Pellentesque sed ipsum nisl. Fusce volutpat erat tristique dolor congue, ac porttitor mi venenatis. Phasellus tincidunt, nibh sed semper ornare, velit ligula vehicula tortor, et pulvinar urna nunc laoreet augue. Morbi ac justo eu lorem blandit suscipit sit amet in nisl. Suspendisse egestas ipsum sed elit commodo congue. Nullam ultricies egestas interdum. Proin dolor velit, pharetra in imperdiet placerat, malesuada vitae nisi. Phasellus vel rhoncus nunc.</p>

<p>Vestibulum tincidunt sem arcu, sit amet mollis dolor volutpat at. Integer tincidunt vel augue at efficitur. Aenean semper mi urna, sit amet suscipit augue tristique nec. Fusce in metus venenatis, volutpat libero ut, porta sapien. Vestibulum auctor, purus id consequat condimentum, orci sem dignissim velit, vel fermentum libero diam venenatis lorem. Aliquam lacinia scelerisque accumsan. Proin sed euismod lacus. Fusce et leo auctor, efficitur odio et, pellentesque risus. Etiam ultrices arcu ac ipsum rhoncus ullamcorper. Phasellus vel condimentum orci. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam pulvinar euismod vestibulum. Nam nec lorem lobortis, lobortis dui luctus, ullamcorper tellus. Duis et erat pretium eros blandit aliquet id vel mi.</p>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you actually added jQuery? It works fine here. Also, you could shorten that jQuery. 

`$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  
    $('#fixed').removeClass('stick');
    
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > 280) {
    $('#fixed').addClass('stick');
    }
    
   });
});`

By omitting the second if statement. The class will just be removed if scrollTop doesn't equate to the value in the if statement.

Comment: It works, thanks! xD I should just stick with html/css bahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, you just need to add the jquery on html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 280) {
      $('#fixed').addClass('stick');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 281) {
      $('#fixed').removeClass('stick');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Oswald);
body {
  background: url(http://orig02.deviantart.net/240a/f/2016/162/7/f/into_the_white__by_thehartless-da5x0or.png) center fixed no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position-y: 0%;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

a:link {
 color: #8ac3e4;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 1s;
}

a:visited {
 color: #8ac3e4;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
 color: #bde7ff;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 1s;
}

#logo {
  color: #fff;
  font: 65px Oswald;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-top: 8%;
}

#container {
  background: rgba(219, 227, 230, 0.80);
  color: #333;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin-top: 10%;
  font: 15px Open Sans;
  min-width: 850px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

#content {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1% 22%;
}

.thead {
  padding: 3% 0;
  color: #fff;
  font: 25px Open Sans;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.trow1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgb(243, 243, 243);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.guide {
  display: table;
}

.guide .title {
  background: url('http://orig01.deviantart.net/57d2/f/2016/236/b/0/itw_map_sigless_by_marinatedmermaid_dabhbyl_by_thehartless-daf57xe.png') #ddd no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  font: 25px Oswald;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
}

.guide .overlay {
  background: rgba(250, 250, 250, .7);
  padding: 3%;
  
}

.guide_row {
  display: table-row;
}

.guide_nav {
  width: 25%;
  max-width: 225px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #c8cacc;
  padding: 3%;
  color: #fff;
}

#fixed {
  width: auto;
}

#fixed.stick {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}

.guide_nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.guide_nav li {
  background: #9a9b9b;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.guide_nav a:link {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 1s;
}

.guide_nav a:visited {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.guide_nav a:hover,
a:active {
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 1s;
}

.guide_content {
  display: table_cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 3%;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.guide_content:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}


.guide_sep {
  opacity: .2;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

.guide_map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 662px;
  background: url('http://orig01.deviantart.net/57d2/f/2016/236/b/0/itw_map_sigless_by_marinatedmermaid_dabhbyl_by_thehartless-daf57xe.png') no-repeat bottom;
  background-size: cover;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logo">into the white</div>

<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <div class="thead">guide</div>
    <div class="trow1">
      <div class="guide">
        <div class="guide_row">
          <div class="guide_nav">
            <div id="fixed">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#setting">Setting</a></li>
              <li><a href="#map">Map</a></li>
              <li><a href="#lore">Religion & Lore</a></li>
              <li><a href="#culture">Culture</a></li>
              <li><a href="#characters">Characters</a></li>
              <li><a href="#strains">Strains</a></li>
              <li><a href="#ethyr">Ethyr</a></li>
              <li><a href="#leveling">Leveling</a></li>             
              <li><a href="#beastiary">Beastiary</a></li>
              <li><a href="#fauna">Fauna</a></li>
              <li><a href="#rules">Rules</a></li>
              <li><a href="#mechanics">Game Mechanics</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div id="introduction" class="title"><div class="overlay">Introduction</div></div>
          <div class="guide_content">
<p>Phasellus sed metus rhoncus, suscipit odio eu, congue ex. Cras eget velit vitae metus placerat varius sed eget libero. In vestibulum lobortis risus, sed molestie dui commodo id. Vivamus nec placerat nisi, a sollicitudin risus. Vivamus non risus arcu. Morbi ex ante, tincidunt vel rutrum vel, dapibus nec felis. Pellentesque sed ipsum nisl. Fusce volutpat erat tristique dolor congue, ac porttitor mi venenatis. Phasellus tincidunt, nibh sed semper ornare, velit ligula vehicula tortor, et pulvinar urna nunc laoreet augue. Morbi ac justo eu lorem blandit suscipit sit amet in nisl. Suspendisse egestas ipsum sed elit commodo congue. Nullam ultricies egestas interdum. Proin dolor velit, pharetra in imperdiet placerat, malesuada vitae nisi. Phasellus vel rhoncus nunc.</p>
          </div>
          <div id="map" class="title"><div class="overlay">Map</div></div>
          <div class="guide_map">
            </div>
          <div id="setting" class="title"><div class="overlay">Setting</div></div>
          <div class="guide_content">
<p>Phasellus sed metus rhoncus, suscipit odio eu, congue ex. Cras eget velit vitae metus placerat varius sed eget libero. In vestibulum lobortis risus, sed molestie dui commodo id. Vivamus nec placerat nisi, a sollicitudin risus. Vivamus non risus arcu. Morbi ex ante, tincidunt vel rutrum vel, dapibus nec felis. Pellentesque sed ipsum nisl. Fusce volutpat erat tristique dolor congue, ac porttitor mi venenatis. Phasellus tincidunt, nibh sed semper ornare, velit ligula vehicula tortor, et pulvinar urna nunc laoreet augue. Morbi ac justo eu lorem blandit suscipit sit amet in nisl. Suspendisse egestas ipsum sed elit commodo congue. Nullam ultricies egestas interdum. Proin dolor velit, pharetra in imperdiet placerat, malesuada vitae nisi. Phasellus vel rhoncus nunc.</p>

<p>Vestibulum tincidunt sem arcu, sit amet mollis dolor volutpat at. Integer tincidunt vel augue at efficitur. Aenean semper mi urna, sit amet suscipit augue tristique nec. Fusce in metus venenatis, volutpat libero ut, porta sapien. Vestibulum auctor, purus id consequat condimentum, orci sem dignissim velit, vel fermentum libero diam venenatis lorem. Aliquam lacinia scelerisque accumsan. Proin sed euismod lacus. Fusce et leo auctor, efficitur odio et, pellentesque risus. Etiam ultrices arcu ac ipsum rhoncus ullamcorper. Phasellus vel condimentum orci. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam pulvinar euismod vestibulum. Nam nec lorem lobortis, lobortis dui luctus, ullamcorper tellus. Duis et erat pretium eros blandit aliquet id vel mi.</p>
          </div>
          <div id="lore" class="title"><div class="overlay">Religion & Lore</div></div>
          <div class="guide_content">
<p>Phasellus sed metus rhoncus, suscipit odio eu, congue ex. Cras eget velit vitae metus placerat varius sed eget libero. In vestibulum lobortis risus, sed molestie dui commodo id. Vivamus nec placerat nisi, a sollicitudin risus. Vivamus non risus arcu. Morbi ex ante, tincidunt vel rutrum vel, dapibus nec felis. Pellentesque sed ipsum nisl. Fusce volutpat erat tristique dolor congue, ac porttitor mi venenatis. Phasellus tincidunt, nibh sed semper ornare, velit ligula vehicula tortor, et pulvinar urna nunc laoreet augue. Morbi ac justo eu lorem blandit suscipit sit amet in nisl. Suspendisse egestas ipsum sed elit commodo congue. Nullam ultricies egestas interdum. Proin dolor velit, pharetra in imperdiet placerat, malesuada vitae nisi. Phasellus vel rhoncus nunc.</p>

<p>Vestibulum tincidunt sem arcu, sit amet mollis dolor volutpat at. Integer tincidunt vel augue at efficitur. Aenean semper mi urna, sit amet suscipit augue tristique nec. Fusce in metus venenatis, volutpat libero ut, porta sapien. Vestibulum auctor, purus id consequat condimentum, orci sem dignissim velit, vel fermentum libero diam venenatis lorem. Aliquam lacinia scelerisque accumsan. Proin sed euismod lacus. Fusce et leo auctor, efficitur odio et, pellentesque risus. Etiam ultrices arcu ac ipsum rhoncus ullamcorper. Phasellus vel condimentum orci. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam pulvinar euismod vestibulum. Nam nec lorem lobortis, lobortis dui luctus, ullamcorper tellus. Duis et erat pretium eros blandit aliquet id vel mi.</p>
          </div>
          <div id="culture" class="title"><div class="overlay">Culture</div></div>
          <div class="guide_content">
<p>Phasellus sed metus rhoncus, suscipit odio eu, congue ex. Cras eget velit vitae metus placerat varius sed eget libero. In vestibulum lobortis risus, sed molestie dui commodo id. Vivamus nec placerat nisi, a sollicitudin risus. Vivamus non risus arcu. Morbi ex ante, tincidunt vel rutrum vel, dapibus nec felis. Pellentesque sed ipsum nisl. Fusce volutpat erat tristique dolor congue, ac porttitor mi venenatis. Phasellus tincidunt, nibh sed semper ornare, velit ligula vehicula tortor, et pulvinar urna nunc laoreet augue. Morbi ac justo eu lorem blandit suscipit sit amet in nisl. Suspendisse egestas ipsum sed elit commodo congue. Nullam ultricies egestas interdum. Proin dolor velit, pharetra in imperdiet placerat, malesuada vitae nisi. Phasellus vel rhoncus nunc.</p>

<p>Vestibulum tincidunt sem arcu, sit amet mollis dolor volutpat at. Integer tincidunt vel augue at efficitur. Aenean semper mi urna, sit amet suscipit augue tristique nec. Fusce in metus venenatis, volutpat libero ut, porta sapien. Vestibulum auctor, purus id consequat condimentum, orci sem dignissim velit, vel fermentum libero diam venenatis lorem. Aliquam lacinia scelerisque accumsan. Proin sed euismod lacus. Fusce et leo auctor, efficitur odio et, pellentesque risus. Etiam ultrices arcu ac ipsum rhoncus ullamcorper. Phasellus vel condimentum orci. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam pulvinar euismod vestibulum. Nam nec lorem lobortis, lobortis dui luctus, ullamcorper tellus. Duis et erat pretium eros blandit aliquet id vel mi.</p>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```